# Azure Pipelines - Setting Custom Variable to Build Number

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my Azure Build Pipeline (classic, not YAML) I set my build number to be the branch name and then a revision number variable. This was my process for that:
Pipelines -> Pipelines -> {my pipeline} -> Edit -> Options -> Build Number Format

```
$(SourceBranchName)$(Rev:.r)
```

In my testing, that works great.

Now, in my Release Pipeline, the first script I run is a PowerShell script that takes the build number, and applies it to a local variable (MyBuild) I created. The script is as follows:

```
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
$buildNumber = $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$pipeline.variables.MyBuild.value = $buildNumber
```

This variable is used later in the pipeline to create a folder that houses my release files.

```
$(BuildDirectory)/$(MyBuild)/Debug
```

For some reason, my variable is always one build behind. For example, if my build number is master.5, the folder that is created by my Release Pipeline is master.4. I have tried changing the order my scripts are in the pipeline, but that doesn't solve anything. It is weird because my Build Pipeline is correct (always named properly, ex. master.1, master.2, master.3, etc.) but my Release Pipeline variable is always one revision behind.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell script to update the custom build number

```
- powershell: |
[string]$version="$(Build.Repository.Name)_SomeCustomData_$(Build.BuildId)"
Write-Output "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(Version)"
displayName: Set Build Number
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works well. Below is my reproduction, you can refer to:

In release pipeline :

```
Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyBuild]$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

[image]

```
md $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/$env:MyBuild/Debug
```

[image]

Select build source as release artifact, default version select **Latest**, enable `Continuous deployment trigger`. This creates a release every time a new build is available.

Test reuslt:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In addition, the point I am confused about is how do you use the `$(BuildDirectory)` in the release pipeline? `Agent.BuildDirectory`:
The local path on the agent where all folders for a given **build pipeline** are created.  This predefined variable should not be available in the release pipeline, we should use `Agent.ReleaseDirectory`.You can refer to [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables).

Comment: Actually the same for me. I tested this and got the same. @dotnetdev Are you sure you have release triggered for latest build?

Comment: Thank you, I am going to rework some things and I will report back. As for the BuildDirectory variable, sorry, I should have explained that. It is another custom variable that just points to the directory where the folder is created. Ex.: C:/Users/Public. I will also add that for the 'copy files' task, I don't use a PowerShell script. I clicked 'Add task', and selected the 'Copy Files' task. I then just choose the source folder and target folder for the transfer (that is working OK).

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I just made my script look identical to yours, and my build finished with the build number being master.7 (which is correct). But the MyBuild variable in the release pipeline was updated to master.6. The output of my script says the variable was set to master.6, and I checked the created folder and it is master.6 as well... I have no idea where this is going wrong.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Yes, I ensured that Default Version is set to Latest by going to Pipelines -> Pipelines -> {my pipeline} -> Edit -> {my pipeline artifact} -> Default Version.

Comment: @dotnetdev `Pipelines -> Pipelines -> {my pipeline} -> Edit -> {my pipeline artifact} -> Default Version` I am confused about this step. If you are not using yaml, you should modify the default version in `Pipeline-> Release-> Artifacts`

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Ok, so by going there, Default version is set to "Latest from the default branch", and my Default branch is set to "master". Should the default branch be left with master? If I create a new branch and work off of that, would I then change the default branch to the new one?

Comment: @dotnetdev I think according to your situation, you should choose [Build Source type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UUeI.png) as artifact, specify the build pipeline as the source so that your `buildNumber` will be obtained in the release pipeline in real time. According to your comment, you are using `Azure Repo` source type.

Comment: Under artifacts, I have two there. One is a build (and the source is properly specified as the pipeline name and default version is set to Latest), the second artifact is an Azure repo (default branch is master, default version is Latest from the default branch). Im wondering if [this](https://littlekendra.com/2019/09/02/setting-a-custom-variable-in-an-azure-devops-pipeline-with-powershell/) has anything to do with why this variable isn't being properly updated?

Comment: @dotnetdev You can enable `Continuous deployment trigger` for build type artifact, then manually create a build to automatically trigger the release to see if the issue still exists. Normally, as long as you have the latest build as the artifact source, you can get the latest `buildNumber` in the release.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Thanks, I'll give that a shot. Would it make a difference that this is a variable that I set in `Pipelines -> {my pipeline} -> Variables tab -> Pipeline Variables`?

Comment: For most of the time you are not talking with me but with @HughLin-MSFT ;)